# Solve the equation : $x^2 − 6 |x − 2| − 28 = 0$

Tags: absolute-value, quadratics

The following is an absolute value quadratic equation that I want to solve:
 $$x^2 − 6 |x − 2| − 28 = 0$$
Here is what I did :

$x^2 − 6 |x − 2| − 28 = 0$

$x^2 − 6 |x − 2| − 28 = 0$

$-6|x-2|=28-x^2$

$6|x-2|=x^2-28$

$6x-12=x^2-28$  or  $28-x^2$
(Is this step correct ?)

Solving this two quadratic equations I get the answers $x=-2,8,-10,4$

But when I actually substitute these in the original equation I see that only $x=8,-10  $ satisfy and other two solutions are invalid . Why so?

Comment: a small question: why have you assumed $x$ to be real?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee  maybe because the problem comes from a question paper which doesn't expect me to know about complex numbers ( even though I do ) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

First of all, let $x=a+ib$ where $a,b$ are real

So, we have $$(a+ib)^2-28=6|a+ib-2|\implies a^2-b^2-28+2ab i=6\sqrt{(a-2)^2+b^2}$$

Equating the imaginary parts, we have $ab=0$

If $a=0,-(b^2+28)=6\sqrt{4+b^2}>0$ which is impossible

So, $b$ must be $0\implies x$ must be real

We know for real $m,$ $$|m|=\begin{cases} +m &\mbox{if } m\ge0 \\
-m & \mbox{if } m<0 \end{cases} $$

$$\text{So, }|x-2|=x-2\text{ if } x-2\ge0 \iff x\ge2$$

In that case, we have $$x^2-6(x-2)-28=0\implies x^2-6x-16=0\implies x=8\text{ or } -2$$

But we have $x\ge2,$ so we need to discard the solution $x=-2$

Similarly for $|x-2|=-(x-2)$ if $x-2<0\iff x<2$

Comment: Thanks for exploring the case where x maybe complex ! It taught me a lot.

Comment: @AGoogler, my pleasure. My point is in such problems there can be some complex solutions as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you consider $x\ge 2$ and $x<2$ separately, then you have the following equations respectively:

$$x^2-6(x-2)-28=0\to x^2-6x-16=0$$

$$x^2+6(x-2)-28=0\to x^2+6x-40=0$$

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do u mean by "same solutions"?

Comment: I mean that These equations also yield  x=10,-4,8,-2 which is same as the solutions obtained by me .

Comment: @AGoogler: Well, you get them right, but you should select them appropriately. When $x=8,x=-2$, in fact, you assumed $x\ge 2$ so $x=-2$ cannot be our accepted solution.

Comment: Yes you're right , I understand it now.

Comment: @BabakS.: ANother nice solution with beautiful pictures! +1

Answer (score 1):

Once you know that $6|x-2| = x^2-28$, you know that $x^2 - 28$ must be non-negative. This accounts for why $-2$ and $4$ are not solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get to $6|x-2|=x^2-28$, you need to consider two cases.

### Case $x \ge 2:$

If $x \ge 2$, then $6x-12 = x^2-28 \implies x^2-6x-16=0 \implies (x+2)(x-8)=0
\implies x \in \{-2, 8\}$ But we assumed $x \ge 2$, so we have to reject $x=-2$ as an extraneous root. Hence if $x \ge 2$, then $x=8$.

### Case $x < 2:$

If $x < 2$, then $12-6x = x^2-28 \implies x^2+6x-40=0 \implies (x-4)(x+10)=0
\implies x \in \{4, -10\}$ But we assumed $x < 2$, so we have to reject $x=4$ as an extraneous root. Hence if $x < 2$, then $x=-10$.